# How to detech object is over another with RaphaelJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

Can I detetect somehow one object is moved over another object wiht `Raphael.js`?

I use the basic startMove(), move(), stop() methods to drag and drop objects:

```
var startSystemMove = function() {
    this.odx = 0;
    this.ody = 0;
};
var moveSystem = function(dx, dy) {
    this.translate(dx - this.odx, dy - this.ody);
    this.odx = dx;
    this.ody = dy;
};
var stopSystemMove = function(dx, dy) {
    // do nothing...
};
```

Here are objects:

```
var r1 = paper.rect(20, 105, 122, 23).attr({
    'fill':'#fff',
    'fill-opacity':'0.5',
    'stroke-width':'3',
    'stroke':'#fff',
    'cursor':'move'
});
var r2 = paper.rect(200, 200, 100, 100).attr({
    'fill':'#fff',
    'fill-opacity':'0.5',
    'stroke-width':'3',
    'stroke':'#fff',
    'cursor':'move'
});
```

Setting up draggable:

```
r1.drag( moveSystem, startSystemMove, stopSystemMove );
r2.drag( moveSystem, startSystemMove, stopSystemMove );
```

How can I detech one of the object is moved over the other one?

Comment: Should it be enough to detect whether cursor position is over another object while dragging, like in drag and drop?

Comment: Not enough, because if you move a rectangle I need to stop moving when it impinge with the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with raphael.js but here's a function i created, you might be able to implement in your code.

I used it with the jquery ui draggable. See jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/qnMjc/5/). Hope this helps

```
   $(function()
  {
      $(".block").draggable(
      {
          stop: function(event, ui)
          {
              $(this).css({position: "absolute"});
          }
      });

      $(".block").on("drag",function()
      {
         var hasCollided = collision(this, ".block");          
         if(hasCollided){return false;}    
      });
  });

  function collision(obj, collideObj)
    {
        var collidedElements = new Object();
        var collided = false;

        $(obj).each(function(){
        var player = $(this);
        var playerWidth = $(this).width();
        var playerHeight = $(this).height();
        var playerPosition = player.offset();
        var playerLeft = playerPosition.left;
        var playerRight = playerLeft + player.width();
        var playerTop = playerPosition.top;
        var playerBottom = playerTop + player.height();

        collidedElements.first = player;

        $(collideObj).not(obj).each(function()
        {
            var block = $(this);
            var blockPosition = block.offset();
            var blockLeft = blockPosition.left;
            var blockRight = blockLeft + block.width();
            var blockTop = blockPosition.top;
            var blockBottom = blockTop + block.height();

            if( playerLeft < blockRight &&
                playerLeft > blockLeft &&
                playerBottom > blockTop +10 &&
                playerTop < blockBottom -10)
                {
                    // alert('Collision on left side'); // Debug Code //
                    /*block.removeClass("block");
                    block.toggle("explode", 0);*/            
                    $(player).css({position:"absolute",left: blockRight +1});
                    collided = true;
                    collidedElements.second = $(this);
                    return true;
                }
            if( playerRight > blockLeft &&
                playerRight < blockRight &&
                playerBottom > blockTop + 10 &&
                playerTop < blockBottom - 10)
                {
                    //alert("Collision on right side"); // Debug Code //
                    /*block.removeClass("block");
                    block.toggle("explode", 0);*/
                    $(player).css({position:"absolute",left: blockLeft - (playerWidth +1)});
                    collided = true;
                    collidedElements.second = $(this);
                    return true;
                }
            if( playerTop < blockBottom  &&
                playerTop > blockTop &&
                playerLeft < blockRight -10 &&
                playerRight > blockLeft + 10)
                {
                    //alert("Collision on bottom side"); // Debug Code //
                    /*block.removeClass("block");
                    block.toggle("explode", 0);*/

                    $(player).css({ position:"absolute", top: blockBottom +1});
                    collided = true;
                    collidedElements.second = $(this);
                    return true;
                }
            if( playerBottom > blockTop &&
                playerBottom < blockBottom &&
                playerLeft < blockRight -10 &&
                playerRight > blockLeft +10)
                {
                    //alert("Collision on top side"); // Debug Code //
                    /*block.removeClass("block");
                    block.toggle("explode", 0);*/
                    $(player).css({position:"absolute",top: blockTop - (playerHeight+ 1)});
                    collided = true;
                    collidedElements.second = $(this);
                    return true;
                }           
        });
        });
        if(collided)
        {return collidedElements;}
        else{return false;}


    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this function has some bug on jsfiddle.

Comment: I think i fixed most of the bugs it had.